# Ajax request duplicates html content on second request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I want to do an AJAX request and prepend its html block (which contains a div with the `id = "IdOfHtmlBlock"`) when clicking on link 1 in my DOM:

```
$("#link1").on("click", function(){
 $.get("myBlock.html", function(data){
 $(".wrapper").prepend(data);
 });
});
```

That can afterwards be removed when clicking on link2 in my DOM:

```
$("#link2").on("click", function(){
 $('#IdOfHtmlBlock').remove();
});
```

The problem is when I click link1 again it will prepend `myBlock.html` twice.

Thanks in advance

edit:

My HTML before I click link1:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="someOtherDiv"></div>
</div>
```

My HTML after I click link1:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="IdOfHtmlBlock"></div>
 <div class="someOtherDiv"></div>
</div>
```

`IdOfHtmlBlock`should be removed after I clicked on link2, and so on...

Comment: Don't you have some other `.wrapper` element in `myBlock.html` (wrapping `#chapters` for example) ?

Comment: if you want your click event to work only one time.. then use .one() function instead of .on()

Comment: Can you post the HTML before and after the AJAX call?

Comment: Can you try `$(".wrapper").eq(0).prepend(data);` ?

Comment: the problem is that data itself will grow each time I click link1.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
$("#link1").on("click", function(){
 $.get("myBlock.html", function(data){
 $(".wrapper").html(data);
 });
});
```

Comment: This will replace all the html in wrapper - not ideal if there is more in there than purely what is being prepended.

Comment: but probably that is what is causing the duplicate stuff

Comment: yep, this will replace all of the wrapper's content. I could just put a div inside the wrapper and change its html. but then I'd have an unnecessary div more...

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the **#IdOfHtmlBlock** already exists in your DOM before appending it.

This example will remove it if it already exists before prepending it again:

```
$("#link1").on("click", function(){
 if($('#IdOfHtmlBlock').length > 0) {
  $('#IdOfHtmlBlock').remove();
 }
 $.get("myBlock.html", function(data){
 $(".wrapper").prepend(data);
 });
});
```

You could also decide not to remove and re-add it ofcourse ...